# Develop User based Applications using SMP

Tags: sybase, sup, sap-smp

Can user based apps be Developed using SMP (SAP Mobile Platform) I am only aware that this platform is targeted towards enterprises, but I wonder if there are any chances to develop user Apps with SMP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, consumer apps can be created with SUP/SMP

[Mobile Applications for Consumers](http://www54.sap.com/pc/tech/mobile/software/solutions/applications/consumer-apps.html)

[SAP Mobile Platform @ SAP Community Network](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-8803) - Includes examples, tutorials and whitepapers - mostly geared towards Enterprise apps, but it's still a good resource.